# Selenium Grid service

Tags: selenium

Can anyone recommend a good Selenium Grid "host" for running tests?  Instead of having to set up my own network of testing machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm personally partial to [Sauce Labs](http://saucelabs.com/). For me, the recorded screencasts of your tests is really the key feature. Essentially you just point your existing tests at a sauce server instead of your localhost and you're good to go. One slight drawback is that they don't have Mac instances available for test. They offer a free trial to get you started.

The major thing sauce doesn't handle well is load/performance testing. For that, look at [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com/performance-testing). Essentially, you're driving load tests with real browsers using selenium scripts.

I've heard good things about [PushToTest](http://www.pushtotest.com/) but never used them.

One thing to note is that these are all Selenium 1.x providers. Selenium 2 doesn't have a grid yet, but that should be coming soon.

Comment: They've now added Mac testing. https://saucelabs.com/docs/platforms

Answer (score 0):

Selenium [Grid2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) is now available.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at services, and the two most comparable for grid testing look to be sauce labs as mentioned above, and also [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/accounts/subscriptions) which offers a cheaper "unlimited" package I believe. It has 10 parallel users, which I'm not certain if those compare to VMs that sauce labs uses in the same way. This project requires testing over a full suite of browser variations, so the parallel and unlimited aspects are key factors for us.